# When use a JoinType in Criteria ? Hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, join, criteria

I'm a bit confused about when use a join with Criteria. Example of what I'm talking about:

```
.createAlias("cars", "c", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
```

Here are the different JoinType:

```
LEFT_OUTER_JOIN
INNER_JOIN
LEFT_OUTER_JOIN
NONE
RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN
```

When we map entities with Hibernate there is already a "JoinType" automatically (is that an INNER_JOIN ?).

Simple example with user - car:

User class (table name USERS)

```
class User {
   @Id
   @Column(name="ID_USER")
   private int idUser;

   @Column(name="NAME")
   private String name;

   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn(name="ID_USER")
   private Set<Car> cars;
}
```

And Car class (table name CARS):

```
class Car{
   @Id
   @Column(name="ID_CAR")
   private int idCar;

   @Column(name="MODEL)
   private String model;

   @Column(name="ID_USER")
   private int idUser;
}
```

If I have a user u and i type u.getCars() which Join is it mapped by default ?

If I want for example results of:

```
SELECT * FROM Users u LEFT JOIN Cars c on u.id_user = c.id_user
```

Then is that correct to use that :

```
Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(User.class);
c.createAlias("cars", "c", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
return c.list();
```

(And then I loop on User and Car to search what I'm looking for).

And if I'm looking for that:

```
SELECT * FROM Users u INNER JOIN Cars c on u.id_user = c.id_user
```

Am I right saying I have no need to create a JoinType.INNER_JOIN ?
If I'm, JoinType.INNER_JOIN is useless when I already have map entites ?

I have to map a lot of complex tables using a lot of join and I'm a little muddled !

Answer (score 0):

> When we map entities with Hibernate there is already a "JoinType" automatically (is that an INNER_JOIN ?).

Assuming you have marked the `oneToMany` association as `Fetch.EAGER`. In that case when you load `User` object via `hibernate criteria`, it uses `LEFT OUTER JOIN` by default, unless you override it in `Criteria`. If you have not marked it as `FetchType.EAGER`, it will be lazy and so no join by default, again, unless you override it in `Criteria`.

> If I have a user u and i type u.getCars() which Join is it mapped by default ?

For EAGER loading refer above. If lazy and it is within the same session you are calling `u.getCars`, it will fire a new SELECT to load cars based on the `userId` and so no join.

> Am I right saying I have no need to create a JoinType.INNER_JOIN ? If I'm, JoinType.INNER_JOIN is useless when I already have map entites ?

Refer above, by default it is LEFT OUTER JOIN if it is EAGER and unless overidden in `Criteria`.

On suggestion, - It would be good idea to view the SQLs that hibernate is actually firing  in the background via `enable show_sql property` with different `FetchTypes` and `Criteria JOIN Types`, because based on your entiy mappings the count/complexity of SQL queries might be different.

Comment: It's less confused now, thank you ! If it's a lazy fetch and I call u.getCars(); it will be a LEFT OUTER JOIN too no ?

Comment: If the association is LAZY, by default NO JOIN. And so, with LAZY you are calling `u.getCars`, it will fire a `new SELECT to load cars based on the userId` and so no join.